# Weird result of using scanf "%f" to read a float number and then assign to double

Tags: c, scanf

I just met a problem in C. Following is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    double num = 0;

    printf("Please enter a number: ");
    scanf("%f", &num);
    printf("The entered number is %f", num);

    return 0;
}
```

For some reason, no matter what number is entered from keyboard, the value of `num` keeps the same as `0`. Of course, if I change the data type of `num` to `float`, then everything will be fine. But I just want to know why the above code does not work. My understanding is C automatically converts `float` to `double`, so the above code should work fine. I wonder if anybody can kindly provide further explanation.

Thanks.

Comment: Ask yourself this "Where do the other 32-bits go?"

Comment: When you compiled with warnings, what warnings did you get?

Comment: If you didn't get a warning like `format specifies type 'float *' but the argument has type 'double *'`, it's time to turn up your compiler's warning level, or get a better compiler.

Answer (score 8):

The correct `scanf` conversion format specifier for `double` is `%lf`, not `%f`. By using the wrong specifier, your program is invoking undefined behavior, which means that anything can happen (i.e. your program may crash or print wrong output).

> My understanding is C automatically converts `float` to `double`

This statement is correct for `printf`, but not for `scanf`. When calling `printf` with a `float` variadic argument, the `float` is promoted to `double`. This is called a [default argument promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Default_argument_promotions). However, a `float *` is never promoted to a `double *`. This applies both to `printf` and `scanf`, but is more relevant to `scanf`, because `scanf` makes more use of pointers.

The underlying reason for this behavior is that with `printf`, variables are passed by value, so that a `float` can easily be promoted to a `double` and `printf` therefore does not have to distinguish between a `float` and a `double`. However, with `scanf`, variables are usually passed by pointer, because `scanf` is not interested in the value of a variable, but rather its address, as it needs to know where to write the value of the variable. In order to write the value, `scanf` must also know the type and size of the variable. Therefore, `scanf` must distinguish between a `float` and a `double`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `%lf` format specifier to read a double.